# UICollectionView Cell Width Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView`with custom height and width but when i launch the app, all those cells which are initially visible to screen are perfectly set with respect to my give Height and Width but when i scroll down it reduce the cell width.
[image: Here is the screenshot]

Here are the methods for setting Height and Width, Spacing etc.

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5.0;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5.0f;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.collectionView setNeedsLayout];
    [self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
    CGFloat width = self.collectionView.frame.size.width;
    return CGSizeMake((width/2)-5, 220);
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return [listOfRetailers_ count];
}
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    BDRetailerCollectionViewCell *newCell = (BDRetailerCollectionViewCell*)cell;
    UIFont *font = newCell.brandName.font;
    [newCell.brandName setFont:[font fontWithSize:12]];
    [newCell setNeedsLayout];
    [newCell layoutIfNeeded];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from this method

```
(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
[self.collectionView setNeedsLayout];
[self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: I have solved it but any way thanks for your answer.